# System-wide RVM to replace a home directory loaded on different architectures

Tags: ruby, rvm

I saw some questions like this already, but it seems that system-wide RVM has been deprecated, so none of the answers apply.

I have an NFS-mounted home directory which is accessible to me when I login to any number of different machines in our lab. As such, a locally-compiled Ruby will break when I try to use it on these different machines -- as they have different architectures.

I installed RVM as superuser, but I can't figure out how to direct my regular user account to use the superuser-selected Ruby. Instead it always tries to use the one in `~/bin`.

What is the appropriate way to select the global Ruby?

Comment: Do you have 2 instances of RVM Running (Superuser and regular user?) If not. A simple bash function could take care of that though.

Comment: `ps ax |grep rvm` displays no instances running.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this same issue for quite a while.  I ended up doing the following:

Install rvm with the following command line (note:  the --path option is not mentioned in the usage, so I don't know how supported it is, but it worked for me), with the appropriate architecture in the path:

```
rvm-installer --path ~/tools/x86_64/rvm --version latest
```

Install for whatever architectures you want to be able to support.  (note: make sure you don't have a .rvmrc file overriding the path, especially during the second install.)

Then add the following to your .bashrc/.bash_profile:

```
OS=$(uname -s)
if [[ $OS = Linux ]] ; then
>   ARCH=$(uname -m | sed 's/i.86/i686/')
elif [[ $OS = FreeBSD ]] ; then
>   ARCH=$(uname -m | sed 's/i.86/i686/')
elif [[ $OS = Darwin ]] ; then
>   ARCH=mac
else
>   ARCH=unknown
fi
export ARCH
```

There will be a line added by the installer in your .bash_profile that sets up the rvm function, change it to look like this:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/tools/$ARCH/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/tools/$ARCH/rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

You should also edit your .rvmrc file to have the following:

```
export rvm_path="$HOME/tools/$ARCH/rvm"
```

I haven't had time to fully test out this setup, but at least it appears to be invoking the correct version of RVM on the different platforms.

Good luck!

Comment: been using this setup for a few days now, and it seems to be working well, hope it works for you!

Comment: I'm getting a strange error: `/usr/local/rvm/scripts/base: line 42: /usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/bundler: No such file or directory`. Tried installing bundler, but it didn't help. Sure enough, `bundler` is missing from that directory.

Comment: are you using rvmsudo and rvm exec?  If it's looking in /usr/local/rvm it thinks you are running as root.